# Question about C# inheritance with similar interfaces

Tags: c#

I was recently working on a project where I needed to have the following functionality:

```
public interface IStart
{
    public void StartStarting();
    public bool IsDoneStarting();
}

public interface IEnd
{
    public void StartEnding();
    public bool IsDoneEnding();
}
```

These two interfaces basically do the same thing:

```
public interface IDo
{
    public void StartDoing();
    public bool IsDoneDoing();
}
```

Is there somehow a way to inherit IDo twice rather than IStart and IEnd individually? I highly doubt it, but it would certainly be convenient.

Comment: You can't implement an interface twice, so it's not clear what you're trying to do. And there's no programmatic connection between the two interfaces other than the method names. What's wrong with inheriting both? What do you have now that you don't like?

Comment: That's about what I expected. I didn't expect there to be a better solution, but I thought it was worth the ask. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `:IDo<Eat>, IDo<Drink>, IDo<Poop>` ? (Not that I think it likely to be useful in real coe, but at least it is somewhat "inherit twice")

Answer (score 2):

Another option to consider is using composition over inheritance. In a composition scenario, the `IStart` and `IEnd` implementations would be passed in to the .ctor, then accessed as properties.

Code is worth a thousand words...

```cs
public interface IDo
{
    void StartDoing();
    bool IsDoneDoing();
}

public interface IStart : IDo { }
public interface IEnd : IDo { }

public interface IWorker
{
    IStart Start { get; }
    IEnd End { get; }
}

public class Worker : IWorker
{
    public IStart Start { get; }
    public IEnd End { get; }

    public Worker( IStart start, IEnd end )
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done to inherit one interface to the next. If you want a commonality expressed as such, I suggest using an abstract class which pulls in both interfaces and expresses that *syntactic sugar* you seek as such:

```
public abstract class IDo :  IStart, IEnd
{
    public void StartDoing() { StartStarting(); }
    public bool IsDoneDoing() { return IsDoneEnding() }


    public virtual void StartStarting() {}
    public virtual bool IsDoneStarting() { return false; } // Override me.

    public virtual void StartEnding()  { }
    public virtual bool IsDoneEnding() { return false; } // Override me.

}
```